# Please help me get my BlobServiceClient connected

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

Someone tagged this as "answered" lazily.  But the proper reaction should have been, that endpoint(URL) doesn't work for BlobServiceClientBuilder.  You should use BlobContainerClientBuilder or some other means.  I still need help.

### Original Post...

I've been provided this URL but I cannot figure out how to pass it into the BlobContainerClientBuilder or some other means...

https://MYACCOUNTNAME.blob.core.windows.net/data?sv=2022-11-02&si=MYACCOUNTNAME-RITM0155475&sr=c&sig=IkSxxxxxL%2BAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaqk%2BrRsxxxxxx%3D

I have modified the values in the URL slightly for security purposes.

```
    String accountName = "MYACCOUNTNAME"; 
    String accountKey = "IkSxxxxxL+Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaqk+rRsxxxxxx=";
    StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
                 
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                            .endpoint(String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/", accountName))
                            .credential(credential)
                            .buildClient();          
    
    
                 BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                            .endpoint(String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/", accountName))
                            .credential(credential)
                            .buildClient();
```

The code above doesn't throw any exceptions.  But when this code executes....

```
            System.out.println("Listing  containers: ");
            PagedIterable<BlobContainerItem> cblobs3 = blobServiceClient.listBlobContainers();
            for (BlobContainerItem blobItem : cblobs3) {
                System.out.println("This is the blob name: " + blobItem.getName());
            }
```

blobServiceClient.listBlobContainers() throws an exception...

```
Listing  containers: 
com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: If you are using a StorageSharedKeyCredential, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate method call.
If you are using a SAS token, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate generateSas method call.
Please remember to disable 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign' before going to production as this string can potentially contain PII.
Status code 403, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:e1eee12a-c01e-0028-3f64-d06c777777770
Time:2023-08-16T17:13:13.6923144Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'FCxxxxxxxxxxZcbGt/yuWKxxxxxxxx8c=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET
```

What am I doing wrong?